# Is there a way to permanently block the --no-select attribute on a page by adding a filter to adblock, for example?

Tags: html, adblock

I'm learning to program and a page that contains pieces of code won't let me copy and run them, is there a way to permanently disable the --no-select attribute on this page? Maybe an adblock filter?
That attribute is in class.

```html
    <div class="s1-description-code s1-description-code--no-select">
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look into user stylesheets, see: https://superuser.com/questions/560539/how-can-i-force-my-css-styles-when-i-visit-a-website

You *can* change your browsers user stylesheet, but the easiest method is to install the Stylish extension on Chrome or Firefox and add this:

```
* {
    user-select: text !IMPORTANT;
}
```

Stylish also allows you to disable the sheet on certain websites, or have per-site custom styles.

This may break things on certain websites, so I recommend you either configure Stylish to not apply the stylesheet on those sites, or you use a more specific selector rather than `*`.

A final caveat, this can be defeated if the website uses `!IMPORTANT`, at which point you may need to look into more involved solutions, such as running JavaScript on page load to remove the offending CSS rules.